# magento import image attribute not inserting in table

Tags: magento

I have following fields in my csv

```
store
websites
attribute_set
type
category_ids
sku
has_options
name
meta_title
meta_description
image
small_image
thumbnail
url_key
url_path
custom_design
page_layout
options_container
gift_message_available
size
caseprice
newbrand
weight
price
special_price
cost
status
tax_class_id
is_recurring
visibility
enable_googlecheckout
description
short_description
meta_keyword
custom_layout_update
special_from_date
special_to_date
news_from_date
news_to_date
custom_design_from
custom_design_to
qty
min_qty
use_config_min_qty
is_qty_decimal
backorders
use_config_backorders
min_sale_qty
use_config_min_sale_qty
max_sale_qty
use_config_max_sale_qty
is_in_stock
low_stock_date
notify_stock_qty
use_config_notify_stock_qty
manage_stock
use_config_manage_stock
stock_status_changed_automatically
use_config_qty_increments
qty_increments
use_config_enable_qty_increments
enable_qty_increments
product_name
store_id
product_type_id
product_status_changed
product_changed_websites
```

All the fileds are inserting properly except the image,thumbnail and small_image.
I have given the path as \media\catalog\product\im
The image paths i have given as im/abc.jpg
When importing it should insert 3 attribute id 74,75,76.But now it is not inserting in the catalog_product_entity_varchar
table
Please suggest the coln.

Answer (score 1):

The key step is the files need to be in the \media\import\ folder, if they are then they are found and moved automatically, otherwise the image field is skipped and that is what you have seen.

A fuller guide is [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/6220/).

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your CSV is, you are missing some required attributes for product images import i.e., **"_media_image"** and **"_media_attribute_id"**

It will work when you specify these attributes in CSV. The correct format for import images via CSV is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r_0c_P3tX48o5gsR2Lj3y_-ez02UVZS_u-8PkuhFRwc/edit?usp=sharing)

For more details, this [link](http://rltsquare.com/blog/?p=170) will be a good read for you.